# WPF: DataGridTextColumn and DataTableComboBoxColumn OnChange

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

Using WPF & MVVM, I have the following data grid with two columns:

```
        <DataGrid Name="RateTableDataGrid"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding RateTableDataView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  MaxHeight="300">

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rate Table" 
                                    Width="75" 
                                    Binding="{Binding RateTable}" 
                                    ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterTextCellStyle}">
                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Match Type" 
                                        Width="100" 
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MatchTypeCollection}}"
                                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding MatchType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>

        </DataGrid>
```

The DataGrid is tied to a DataView and is setup to listen for changes to the ListChanged event:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Dataview of Rate Tables data used by datagrid
    /// </summary>
    public DataView RateTableDataView
    {
        get
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("RateTables");

            try
            {

                using (SQLClass _sql = new SQLClass(_config.DatabaseInfo))
                {
                    using (SqlConnection _conn = _sql.Connection)
                    {
                        if (SelectedPayrollDatabase != null)
                        {
                            // use the chosen Payroll Database from ComboBox
                            SqlConnectionStringBuilder _newConn =
                                    new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(_conn.ConnectionString) { InitialCatalog = SelectedPayrollDatabase };
                            _conn.ConnectionString = _newConn.ConnectionString;

                            // Create new sql command 
                            SqlCommand _cmd = _conn.CreateCommand();
                            _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                                _cmd.CommandText = "aem.S_RateTable_SP";

                            // create new sql data adapter
                            SqlDataAdapter _adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);

                            // Fill the temporary dataset with the data from the data adapter
                            _adapter.Fill(ds);

                            // Set dataview data to that of dataset table
                            _RateTableDataView = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

                            // Add listener for changes to the RateTableDataView
                            _RateTableDataView.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(RateTableChanged);

                            // Rate table is always clean at this point
                            RateTableIsDirty = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This works and the ListChanged event is called but only when I change focus to another row of data within the table.

I would like to be able to be able to execute a method (stored in a VM) that updates another column whenever the value of either of these columns changes without requiring the user to select a different row.

I tried adding an EventTrigger to the each column like this (found on another post):

```
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rate Table" 
                                    Width="75" 
                                    Binding="{Binding RateTable}" 
                                    ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterTextCellStyle}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnded">
                            <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="RateTableCellChanged"  />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
```

but the RateTableCellChanged is never called (even when focus is changed to a different row).

Is there a way to call a method in the VM when the text or the dropdown selection has changed without leaving the row?

Comment: Can you use the OnSelectionChanged event for the ComboBox?  I use that for combo box in a header of the DataGrid, but have not tried it for a ComboBoxColumn type.  It looks like: `<i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged"> <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding . . . }"/></i:EventTrigger>`

Comment: try to use Twoway binding which would  change the value. and add UpdateSourceTrigger as PropertyChanged